# Is it possible to raise a Serializable Isolation Violation in Redshift using only Insert and Select statements?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Just a bit of background: Our software is performing simple, but quite rapid rapid (+/- 1 per second at peak, at times concurrently), `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements against a particular Redshift table.  Sometimes, one of these statements, usually an `INSERT` statement (maybe always?), will throw a Serializable Isolation Violation.  No joins or anything complicated, just inserting a single record, and selecting groups of records based on a filter.

My question: How is it possible to raise a Serializable Isolation Violation in Redshift using only Insert and Select statements?

From my understanding of how Serializable Isolation is intended to work, only things like `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements should break serializability.  I have read the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_serial_isolation.html) over and over and over again, but it doesn't provide any useful examples for really understanding the principles at hand. I figure that maybe I am understanding SI incorrectly.  Can somebody explain (hopefully with an example) how this principle works?

An alternate title for this question could also be:  "Explain Like I'm 5: Serialization Isolation," as it is quite possible that I am asking the wrong question entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
T1:  INSERT A
T2:  INSERT B
T2:  SELECT somethingThatWouldIncludeAIfItWasCommitted 
    => but it was not committed, so it will not be included
    => T1 must be after T2
T1:  SELECT somethingThatWouldIncludeBIfItWasCommitted 
    => T2 must be after T1  => BOOM
```

Comment: "If any serial execution of the concurrent transactions would produce the same results as their concurrent execution, those transactions are deemed 'serializable' and can be run safely."  in your example, running the `Select` statements (in any order) first, then running the `insert` statements (in any order) afterward would appear to pass that rule, wouldn't it?

Comment: You cannot just re-order the statements within a single transaction. The SELECT after the INSERT might have a different result (in the above example presume that both SELECT include the value INSERTed just before).  You can only change how the two transactions are interleaved with eachother (or, in the case of SERIALIZABLE, you cannot interleave them at all).

Comment: Ah, I see, `INSERT A` and `SELECT B` are in the same transaction, while `INSERT B` and `SELECT A` are in another transaction.  There is no way to order those two transaction serially such that each transaction would return the same value as if they had been run individually in isolation, as they each modify each others result.  Got it, I think I understand this a bit more clearly now. it may not solve my immediate problem, but I asked this question in order to gain a deeper understanding of the underlying principle.

Comment: So, it turns out that you were EXACTLY correct, that this is precisely what was happening.  I suppose a followup question would be: What can I do about it?  I have these two transactions hitting the database at the same time, each of them both performing an `insert` and a `select count(*)`.  is there any way I could modify those queries such that this error wouldn't get thrown?

Comment: Is it important that the `select count` happens in the same transaction as the `insert`? Otherwise you could commit before it.